# How to make Outlook Add-in open in the side pane

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I developing an outlook add-in for Office 365 and currently showing it in the grey bar below a mail item's details. So when clicking on the add-in name, I get a pane below it like this:

[image]

However, I want it to display it like Trello in the side pane like this:

[image]

Is there any specific setting in the add-in manifest that I need to include to get it to work like the Trello add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use "VersionOverrides" tag for your manifest. Inside this section you would use...

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
```

and for the action you would "ShowTaskPane" with the resource pointed to the HTML file you would like to load. The example of such manifest you may find at [GitHub for OfficeDev team](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-Scream/blob/master/manifest-outlook-add-in-scream.xml)